# Trying to repaint on different JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have a `JFrame`, inside which I have two `JPanel` instances.

I have used `repaint()` to paint the frame. But the problem is I want two different `repaint()` for the two different panels.

```
Jpanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel.add(image1);  //image1 and image2 is of its own class type.
panel.add(image2);
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize((int)width*2, (int)height);
frame.setVisible(true);

frame.repaint();
```

I know, I haven't used `repaint()` on the `JPanel`,... help in this also.. I got minimal working using this.

Can we, just `repaint()` on a particular `JPanel`?

Comment: `Jpanel panel = new JPanel();` That would not compile.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Dont use `setSize` rather override `JPanel` `getPreferredSize()` and return `Dimension`s which fit the contents being drawn to `Graphic`s object.

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame#repaint` will repaint the entire frame and it's contents.

`JPanel#repaint` will repaint the instance of the panel and it's children.

This will work for all components as they inherit the `repaint` from `Component`

Comment: Yeah.. but I have two different panels and is there anyway to paint different things in two different panels...Since we have only one repaint() function...

Comment: EACH panel has a repaint method.  If you want to draw on a panel, the I suggest you take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Thanks...guess that link should help me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer... wow that link was really helpful. Dunno, How I missed it.

Comment: @JS_VIPER Some days, I feel like I live there ;)